# Import file from google drive into google colab, but make the code accessible for other people

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I'm using some files on a colab project and would like to share both the code and **the ability to execute it** with other people. However, the files are under the `/drive/MyDrive` path, which renders anyone I share the project with unable of running my code.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Put everything (data + notebook) inside a folder, share the folder with them and ask them to copy the folder to their drive.

Comment: Or you can share the data folder in your drive and ask the others to change the path in the code wherever needed.